# How to animate a button in Android to expand sideways?

Tags: java, android, animation, button, android-animation

I want a `Button` (or any `View` for that matter) to expand / stretch out sideways with an animation and I want it to happen at the click of another `Button`. For example, before `Button 1` is pressed, the `Button 2` shouldn't exist. But when `Button 1` is pressed, the `Button 2` should slowly come into existence with both its sides smoothly expanding to left and right to a certain size.

The following is a photo I drew to explain what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

I have looked at several tutorials, but most of them had sliding animation from one fixed end to the other. I have also tried scaling the X & Y of the button from value 0 to 1, but they just don't give the smooth animation effect (they just appear there out of nowhere) and the button doesn't expand / stretch sideways.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 1):

```
// scale down button2 at the start of an activity
btn2.setScaleX(0.1f);

// on the click of button 1 let the button2 scale
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             btn2.animate()
                     .scaleX(4.0f)
                     .setDuration(1000)
                     .setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(2.0f)) //Will give bounce effect to the scaling
                     .start();
         }
 });
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Doesn't any way give the smooth stretch out effect

Answer (score 0):

the smooth animation effect ,you can use ObjectAnimtor.

Comment: But how do I achieve the stretch out / expand effect?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2544) library for `Button 2` animation.
In order to it happen at the click of another Button just call `View.performClick()` for `Button 2` from `Button 1` onClick() method.

Answer (score 0):

first define 2 objects of Animation and Button then create a On Click listener for Button and write these codes in it:

```js
//here i define :Button btnoff 
//Animation animation1
//set on click listener in oncreate
btnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
     animation1 = new ScaleAnimation(0,2,1,1,
     Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
     animation1.setDuration(1200);
     btnOff.startAnimation(animation1);}
     });
```

you can learn more in this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation).